# Selenium and JavaScript: Accessing multiple elements with the same ID

Tags: selenium, xpath

I've got a page (Angular8) with multiple button/input elements having the same ID.

The ID's are, in the order the appear on the page:

```
1: for="lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON"
2: for="lastOppDokument-1-VERGE-VERGEMAL"
...
3: for="lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON"
4: for="lastOppDokument-1-VERGE-VERGEMAL"
```

The elements on lines 1,3 and 2,4 have the same ID.

I'm trying to access the elements using XPath and index like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@for='lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON'])[1]
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@for='lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON'])[2]
```

If I check the size:

```
int x = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//input[@for='lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON'])")).size();
```

it says "2", which is correct.

However, when I try to click those two buttons, the first one (LINE 1) is clicked, but then the next button on the page (LINE 2) i clicked istead of the one on LINE 3.

There's obviously something wrong with my XPath expression, but what? Also, the page is an Angular page, and in the markup code "for" is used to automatically index the ID. But selenium finds the elements (albeit not all the correct ones) using ID. But maybe I need to use something else to identify the correct elements?

UPDATE:

To troubleshoot, I'm skipping the use of a loop and just trying to access the two elements manually:

```
WebElement buttonToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON'])[1]"));
filUtils.uploadFile(buttonToClick, legitimasjonfil);
WebElement buttonToClick2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@for='lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON'])[2]"));
filUtils.uploadFile(buttonToClick2, legitimasjonfil);
```

The uploadFile (and related) methods:

```
public void uploadFile(WebElement id, String filename) {
    id.sendKeys(getAbsolutePathToTestFile(TESTFILER_PATH + "/" + filename));
}

private String getAbsolutePathToTestFile(String path) {
    return copyFileToTargetTempPath(path, path);
}

private String copyFileToTargetTempPath(String originPath, String destinationPath) {
    InputStream resourceAsStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(originPath);
    File destination = new File(TARGET_TEMP_PATH + destinationPath);
    try {
        assert resourceAsStream != null;
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(resourceAsStream, destination);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return destination.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
<td>
 <span class="hb-felt knappesamling-gruppe hb-avstandIngen ng-star-inserted">
 <input class="hb-lastOppFil-input hb-bare-skjermleser" type="file" id="lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON" 
  accept=".pdf,.bmp,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.tiff">
 <label class="hb-knapp hb-knapp--standard hb-spinner-tekst" for="lastOppDokument-0-VERGE-LEGITIMASJON"> Velg fil </label><!---->
 </span>
</td>

<td>
 <span class="hb-felt knappesamling-gruppe hb-avstandIngen ng-star-inserted">
 <input class="hb-lastOppFil-input hb-bare-skjermleser" type="file" id="lastOppDokument-1-VERGE-VERGEMAL" 
  accept=".pdf,.bmp,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.tiff"><label class="hb-knapp hb-knapp--standard hb-spinner-tekst" for="lastOppDokument-1-VERGE-VERGEMAL"> Velg fil </label><!----></span>
 <label class="hb-knapp hb-knapp--standard hb-spinner-tekst" for="lastOppDokument-1-VERGE-VERGEMAL"> Velg fil </label>
</span>
```

Comment: HTML elements should not have the same ID - if they do, it's incorrect (semantically) - browsers will still render the elements tho' - to avoid this headache (and all workarounds you'll have to come up to fix this) it's advisable to simply just make IDs unique

Comment: I know that, but there's nothing I can do about that, since this is embedded into the Angular framework in use, and controlled by the frontend developers.

Comment: You could point it out to the developers (IDs must be unique) - it wouldn’t be your responsibility to fix their carelessness. Point out to your superior that this would create all kinds of troubles in the future because you (and others) will have to keep coming up with workarounds to write a decent test case (when it can be faster, easier if they fix this issue)

Comment: If you are still not able to gain any traction on that, I am sorry

Comment: The attribute `for` can have same `attribute value` (it's not id - this is just an attribute value) so don't worry about much on the unique ID part. The xpath looks correct, It would be great if you can share the logic that you are using to click the elemenst, I suspect there might be an issue in your loop rather the xpath.

Comment: @supputuri I've added the code I'm using to troubleshoot. I'm not using a loop - just trying to access the elements directly, then sending them to a file-upload method.

Comment: There should be a property that is different between two elements, Print the unique property for `buttonToClick2` element before calling the upload method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean? Print what/how? Which unique property?

Comment: can you please share the html of the both the elements

Comment: Done. Added the markup for the two top elements (1 and 2), which should not be identical.